# How to add button to GridView bound to Datatable ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView in in my webform. I set the data source as a DataTable, and bind it. When I tried adding an edit button by selecting "Enable edit/update/delete", it wasn't showing up.

But, I managed to show the button manually. On button click, how do I get the first cell value of the row, of which the button is clicked ?

My GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="SOGridView" runat="server" ShowHeader="False" 
            onrowdatabound="SOGridView_RowDataBound" onrowcommand="SOGridView_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewSO" runat="server"   CommandName="Select" height="40px" 
                                Text="Add" Width="75px" onclick="btnAddNewSO_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField></Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

On Button Click,

```
SOGridView.DataSource = dt;
SOGridView.DataBind();
```

MY DATA TABLE

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col4", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col5", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col6", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col7", typeof(string)));
```

On Button Click in the page,

```
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Col1"] = ddlitemcategory.SelectedValue;
dr["Col2"] = ddlitems.SelectedValue;
dr["Col3"] = textQty.Text;
dr["Col4"] = textDisc.Text;
dr["Col5"] = textAmount.Text;
dr["Col6"] = textPDeliveryDate.Text;
dr["Col7"] = textPShipmentDate.Text;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

SOGridView.DataSource = dt;
SOGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: cam you show your code for binding gridview

Comment: Are you using `BoundColumn` or `<asp:TemplateField` for your column definition?

Comment: I am using <asp:Template Field>. Please see my code.

Answer (score 1):

you just need rewrite code for button as follow

```
<asp:Button ID="addbtn" runat="server"  Text="save" CommandName="SAVE" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
```

and add `onrowcommand` event to gridview and also add datakeyName attribute to gridview.

```
 <asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="Id"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
```

then write code on rowcommand

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "SAVE")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                int id=Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString());
                string deltequer="delete from yourtablename where id='"+id+"'";
            }
        }
```

Comment: This worked well, and I got the GridView's Row index value. As I have mentioned, I am populating the gridview from a datatable. How do I know whether, the row to be edited is same as the row in the Data Table ?

Comment: i didn't get you . tell me what action you wan to perform on click event of button. do you want to update record in database ?

Comment: Actually, I want to delete the record. My gridview is bound to a data table. The button btnAddNewSO, on clicking should delete the row in the GridView, as well as in the Data Table. Sorry for the naming convention. I should have to change it to "DeletSO".

Comment: Is it possible to delet from the Data Table, and not using SQL ?

Comment: "not using sql". from where your data table is populated ?
if you don't want to write sql query then then there are too many other things , like EF or ORM.

Comment: Please see the datatable in my Question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57731/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-roshan).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CommandArgument` to pass in any additional value (first databound field value) to the `CommandName` which you can manipulate in the code behind.

Change your `TemplateField` as below

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewSO" runat="server"   CommandName="Select" height="40px" 
                            Text="Add" Width="75px"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

and then in your code behind.

```
protected void SOGridView_RowCommand(object sender, 
  GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Select")
  {
    // Retrieve the CommandArgument property
    int cellvalue = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); // or convert to other datatype
  }
}
```

Or just pass in the `RowIndex` as the `CommandArgument` and then you can access any control of the respective row using `FindControl`. So now your button definition would become

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddNewSO" runat="server"   CommandName="Select" height="40px" 
                            Text="Add" Width="75px"  CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
```

and your code behind

```
if (e.CommandName == "Select")
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

   // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
   // from the Rows collection.
   GridViewRow row = SOGridView.Rows[index];
   // use FindControl to find any control you want to access from the row collection
}
```

Comment: But, where from do we get the value of Eval("ID") ?
Id it like the first cell header ?

Comment: No that's one of the field in the datasource.

Comment: And how do I use this button to edit item from the data table ?

Comment: You'll have to remove the respective row (matching the key) from the data table and rebind the grid with the updated datasource like `SOGridView.DataSource = dt; SOGridView.DataBind();`